# C# Double Foreach Optimization

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, foreach

I got a problem over here, recently I found this problem with a web project (created in Sitefinity) when I'm trying to get a whole list of articles that I need to add in cache for faster access.

I found that some genius developers XD used to get the whole list of articles that belong to certain category that exists in the Taxon (some property of sitefinity that recognizes that type of category ex: Pregnant - Babies - kids...you got the idea), and have to do some search in an item collection with dynamic content, where has the info about the articles (title, images, styles, texts).

Well, my problem is they did it with a double loop research using ForEach, and my boss wants to "optimize" that loop, cause, well of course, is taking too long to do that loop (sometimes it can be more than 3 or 4 minutes, and yeah, my boss wants to have that process instantly :) ).

here is the code:

```
   foreach (HierarchicalTaxon subt in listWeek)
   {
       foreach (DynamicContent item in myCollection)
       {
            if (item.Organizer.TaxonExists("Category", subt.Id))
            {
                 item.Author = subt.Name;
                 //if (articles.Where(art => art.Author.Equals(item.Author)).Count() == 0)
                 articles.Add(item);
            }
       }
   }
```

So I have to deal with this double loop that has this 2^n implementation, my question is, how can I do it?!?!?!

I was thinking in adding some LINQ as I saw in other threads, but it seems to be way too slower than this actual code.

It looks that myCollection doesn't have a long set of elements, but I'm pretty sure I'll have to use this kind of optimization in other sentences with the same logic in other projects.

please guys, a little back up would be apreciated, is there a possible to do it faster??

---

So here we go, what do you think guys, is this ok??

```
var data = listWeek.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
var iDdata = data.Keys;
var nombresData = data.Values;

foreach (DynamicContent item in myCollection)
{
    if (item.Organizer.TaxonExists("Category", iDdata.First()) )
    {
        item.Author = nombresData.First();
        articlesPrueba1.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Edit: 16/08/2016 --> Not currently working, First of all, I got troubles when I'm trying to access the values of the dictionary, so I attach in separate variables for Id and Name, I think that should do it, but I'm not sure about that.

But then I had this problem, is just doing one round in the content of the dictionary data, it seems obvious, but I thought that'd work, but sadly, it didn't.

---

I was trying to use LINQ:

```
 foreach (HierarchicalTaxon subt in listWeek)
 {
    foreach (DynamicContent item in myCollection.Where(item => item.Organizer.TaxonExists("Category", subt.Id)))
    {
        item.Author = subt.Name;
        articlesPrueba2.Add(item);
        }
    }
 }
```

but I got this exception about the query is not accessing the database, damn you Sitefinity, I Hate You... But nevermind, I don't really care about LINQ.

still in serious optimization problem.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what a profiler says here. You are assuming that the nested loops are the problem, but there are a lot of opportunities in this code for inefficiencies, and it's hard to give you a good answer without seeing what is measurably taking all the time.

Comment: well while I was debugging, my first guess it was the cache, but then I was searching for break points where the project was taking more time in load content, and I got this contentService isolated, where the foreach loop has to check listWeek and my Collection objects, where it took too long for get the the collection of articles with the proper content that I need it.  But well you are right, there could be a lot of other troubles, I'm new in this department, doing support since just a little more than 1 month, from this project running since 2013!!! I think got the idea of how huge it is.

Comment: Understood- but you don't know for sure that it's the nested loops, or maybe the `TaxonExists` method, or even calling `articles.Add`. Use a profiler to make sure, then optimize based on measurements. Once you do that, the dictionary suggestions below should help if it turns out to be the nested loops.

Comment: I was using fiddler, of telerik, the same group that created sitefinity, the CMS that I have to use in Visual Studio, could you suggest me a good profiler?? I'd appreciate it bro.

Comment: I use JetBrains dotTrace, but there are a lot of them out there. Ants is good. A quick google search turned up this free one: https://www.nprofiler.com/. They usually have free trials- give them a go and see what you like.

Comment: alright thanks, also I'm still thinking in this foreach-loop optimization, I wanna check if is possible to improve this code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is very inefficient, that's for sure.

From what I can get out of the code you basically want to check if a Dynamic Content item has a Category and if so get the name of that category and assign it to the Author property.

A better approach would be to loop the collection of the Dynamic content items (only once) and check if the item has a category. If so, then find the taxon using the Taxonomy Manager and get its name/title and assign to it to the dynamic content.

This way you will have to loop the collection once and then query the taxonomies only when needed.

Comment: easy to say pal, you are absolutely right, but you know, my boss said that, and then said, go do your code... but the problem is, I don't know how to do it, and I have to check all the collections, Dynamic Content and Taxonomies. See my problem, I was thinking in putting a break in the inner loop, but I can't do that, cause I'll get less items to add in the articles loop. Look I'm not lazy, is just I'm relative new in this optimization stuff. Plus, we all know Optimization is a very difficult task. Also, I want to clarify, I have to check Category and Author properties to add in articles.

Comment: Dammit I cannot edit, I have to say you are right, after get the Category Name I have to proceed to asign the Name of the author of that article, and then, add that item to my third list "articles". Well the thing is, is possible to that checking all over the two collections "listWeek" and "myCollection" in just one loop??? I know I can add Linq to of those loops to check the "if" condition at the same time in the round, but I think that's even worst in performance terms.

Answer (score -1):

You can optimize the code by converting last week into a `Dictionary`, in the form of KeyValue pairs of Id and Name.

```
 var data = listWeek.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
```

Next, iterate through `myCollection` as you are doing now with a method to find Category from dictionary.

Comment: Why not use a `LINQ JOIN` since anyways you are using LINQ?

Comment: Sure, LINQ JOIN can be used, but I feel the primary optimization can come just by reducing the two loops to one.

Comment: This assumes that the dictionary can be saved. Regenerating the dictionary each time this routine runs would possibly be slower than just doing the nested loops in the first place.

Comment: No. I didn't mean to create the dictionary in loop but outside. So it should be created only once.

Comment: If I use dictionary, I have to convert HierarchicalTaxon subt in dictionary too?? or is possible to do this in one loop?? I can't access to the C# code right now, but for me is more important to understand how I can improve the performance in this loop (specially the inner loop)

Comment: Request comment for -1

Comment: Well, in your question you have mentioned two loops making it n^2, I have suggested a way to reduce it to just one. So, the loop is indeed reduced.

Comment: I'm not following you pal, why is the "-1" to your own answer. Let me update with the suggestion you made, if I get it right, and maybe you can tell if that's correct.

Comment: Saw your edit, that's what I meant. Hope it helps you with performance.

Comment: Didn't work :(, I got problems accessing the values in dictionary in the loop, plus, it just got the items from one round, so, articles just got lesser items than I really need.